# How to efficiently store customer invoice data and filter them by month, date or name

Tags: json, database, data-structures, content-management-system

I am making an invoice management system. I will use react-js. I have to store invoice details like name of seller, name of customer, date, price, products etc. What is the best and most efficient way to store and retrieve the data. I need the data to show a overview of a particular month's sales performance, so I need to filter them by months or even by dates.

Ps: Just starting out with data storage on web so please be kind.

Comment: Do you wish to be persist? I mean that every reload the data will be gone or saved?

Comment: Data would be saved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of ways managing state in a react application, the simplest one is being component state (either with class components by using this.state of by using hooks with useState hook).

If your application is complex I'd recommend using [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or using the [redux](https://redux.js.org/) library.

The following example will get you started (assuming you have the JSON object in the local storage, you can read more about local storage of the browser [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)).

```
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({});
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function load() {
      const data = localStorage.getItem('invoice');
      
      if (data) {
        // local storage has strings stored in it, parse them before set state.
        setState(JSON.parse(data));
      }
    }
    
    load();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{state?.id}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Keep in mind you can create a custom hook that reads the needed argument from local storage (or default if not found), and re-use it in different components

```
function useLocalStorage(key) {
  const [item, setItem] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function load() {
      const data = localStorage.getItem(key);
      
      if (data) {
        setItem(JSON.parse(data));
      }
    }
    
    load():
  }, [key]);
  
  return item;
}


function App() {
  const id = useLocalStorage('id');
  const balance= useLocalStorage('balance');
  
  return (
    <div>
     <span>{id}</span>
     <span>{balance}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```